# Python Create Multi-layer Dynamic Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a 3 layer dictionary. All keys and values are strings and only their presence in the dictionary is important (I want to remove repetition and order is not important).
So this is the function I wrote:

```
def UpdateDic3(key1,key2,key3,val,dic):
  if not key1 in dic.keys():
    dic[key1][key2][key3] = {val}
  elif not key2 in dic[key1].keys():
      dic[key1][key2][key3] = {val}
  elif not key3 in dic[key1][key2].keys():
      dic[key1][key2][key3] = {val}
  else:
      dic[key1][key2][key3].add(val)
  return dic
```

and searching for multilayer dictionary I found this:

```
l=lambda:defaultdict(l)
src_tree =l()

src_tree = UpdateDic3(k1,k2,k3,value,src_tree)
```

Isn't there a better way to make a 3 layer dictionary than the `l=lambda:defaultdict(l)`?

I need a tree structure, with access to every layer's  keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What's wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong with ``defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict))``? That seems a heck of a lot 'better' than a horrible nested-if statement construct. But if really your only goal is to be able to tie a combination of three keys to a single value, then just put the three keys in a tuple and use that as the key for a regular old ``dict``.

Comment: Not only the combination, but each layer's keys are important and I need to have access to every layer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a set filled with tuples.

```
src_tree = set()
str_tree.add((k1, k2, k3))
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer if really the only goal is to be able to test for the existence of a set of three keys. If you want to tie a value to that keyset, just use a dict instead of a set.

Comment: with tuples, I guess I can't figure out which values are under k1.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiple_dictionary(k, v): 
    if len(k) > 1: 
        v = multiple_dictionary(k[1:], v) 
    return {k[0]: v}
```